# Usin a proper preposition in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

*I have decided not to go back to (in?into?) Tax.*

Meaning:

*I had worked in the Tax department before,but have decided not to do the Tax work anymore.*

Is the last sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Which sentence are you asking for feedback on? The first (shorter) one, or the last (longer) one?

Comment: *Into.* You can refer to your field of your profession that way. *I don't want to get back into software anymore.* it's understood that way we say : I'm into software though into means interested, it's common to say you are into for the field you are working in.

Comment: 'to' might also be appropriate if you wanted to refer to that specific department, rather than tax work generally. You go 'to' a location, 'into' a field.

Comment: the first sentence

Comment: Got it! In this contest "into"would be more appropriate since the meaning is to change the field in the profession.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean any tax related occupation, you could say:

> I have decided not to go back **into the tax business**.

*tax business* refers to that occupation in general.

If you mean just that department, you could say:

> I have decided not to go back **to the tax department**.

And *tax* is lower case unless its  part of a proper name.